# Recap on basic thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm having trouble understanding precisely which of the following formulas are valid only for quasi-static processes and which one for all processes.
Can someone check these?

- $Q=nc_v\Delta T$: this is for is isochoric processes, and it seems to me that it makes sense that it's valid for all isochoric processes for two reasons: it seems derived from a special case of $Q=nc\delta T$ where $c$ is the specific heat capacity, and for the first principle of thermodynamics $Q-W=\Delta U$ where $\Delta U$ is the variation of internal energy, which is a state function.
- $Q=nc_p\Delta T$: this is for isobaric processes, and it seems valid for all isobaric processes since it seems coming from $Q=nc\Delta T$, similar to above
- $Q=nRT\log_{e}(\frac{V_f}{V_i})$ for isotermic processes, where $V_f$ is the initial volume, $V_i$ the final volume, $R$ is the gas constant. I have no idea about this

Comment: $\Delta U=Q-W$, not $W-Q$.

Comment: @BobD thanks, do you know why i got all those downvotes?

Comment: @selenio34 questions on this site are more well received if you include the full extent of your own thoughts and attempts at the question, and try and narrow the question down to conceptual issues rather than "check-my-work" / homework style problems, as the former are more generally more useful to other internet users.

Comment: @Poo2uhaha ok thanks. I still don’t understand how my question is “homework style” since it asks about a theoretical/conceptual fact (the validity of the formulas) and I included all my attempts (the first two points, I basically answered myself). Not complaining with you, just sharing my thoughts in hope that someone explains to me instead of downvoting without explaining

Comment: @BobD  I think that your comment is useful only to the extent that it illustrates the necessity of defining your variables.  I don't write either of your expressions.  I write $\Delta U = W + Q$.  It all depends on what you mean by $Q$ and $W$.

Comment: @garyp I didn’t say that is the only version. I’m aware of Q+W, I only wanted to point out that, as far as I know, it is never written W-Q. I simply cited the most common version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - $Q=nc_v\Delta T$:

This is based on the heat capacity at constant volume for a single-phase, pure component substance given by

$$c_{v}=\biggl (\frac{\partial u}{\partial T}\biggr )_v$$

It applies whether the heat transfer is quasi-static or not.

> - $Q=nc_p\Delta T$:

Similarly, this is based on the heat capacity at constant pressure for a single-phase, pure component substance given by

$$c_{p}=\biggl (\frac{\partial h}{\partial T}\biggr )_p$$

It also applies whether the heat transfer is quasi-static or not.

> - $Q=nRT\log_{e}(\frac{V_f}{V_i})$

This is specific to an ideal gas undergoing a quasi-static, reversible isothermal (constant temperature) process.  The external pressure is slowly reduced such that $PV=constant$. For an ideal gas,

$$PV=nRT$$ or
$$P=\frac{nRT}{V}$$

Since temperature is constant, and since for an ideal gas internal energy depends only on temperature, $\Delta U=0$. From the version of the first law where $\Delta U=Q-W$ (to the best of my knowledge it is never written $\Delta U=W-Q$ as you stated) we have $W=Q$. Then

$$Q=W=\int_{Vi}^{Vf}PdV=nRT\int_{Vi}^{Vf}\frac{dV}{V}=nRT\ln\frac{V_{f}}{V_i}$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks! yeah it was just a typo by the way, I learned it as you did